# Modify network shares, but not delete?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, network-shares, ubuntu-9.10, nautilus

How can I make it so that I can modify the files on a network share (client: linux, ubuntu 9.10, network share server: windows 7), or create new files on it, but not delete?  Or at least make it so that I have to authenticate or confirm a deletion of files on that share?

I accidentally deleted a video on a network share that I didn't intend to.  I was able to recover the file, but I would like to prevent this from happening again.

If I could simply change the behavior of nautilus to require a confirmation, or a key combination (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>?) instead of simply using the delete key, this would be sufficient.

Comment: I suspect this is hard since editing a file and saving it is the same as deleting the original and saving the new file with the same name. I think your best bet is to modify nautilus behaviour to disable the `Del` key when necessary. But even this might be hard since nautilus may not know (or care) whether the current file is in a local hdd or a network share.

Comment: How do I do this?  I would now simply like to globally change the key from the delete key to a key combination.

Comment: Don't know, it depends on your window manager. Most *nix window managers have utilities to remap keys globally. My suggestion is that you ask a new question on how to do that.